# multidimensional list insertion in python

Tags: python

Create a list (nodes) and then create a 2-d list (nodesRTT), with the size of the nodes list. 
Inside the script there is code which discovers values as follows:

```
nodes = []
nodesRTT = [[len(nodes)]] 
if " from Node:" in line:
   pos = int(line.rpartition('Msg from Node:')[2])
if pos in nodes:
    index = nodes.index(pos) # the node already exists
else:  # node is new, just add it in the nodes list
    nodes.append(pos)#expand the array

# more search code................  

if "RTT:" in line:
    rttCur=int(line.rpartition(":")[2])
    currNode = int(line.split(':')[1])
```

Questions:

1. each time the nodes list is expanded, is the nodesRTT updated too?
2. How do I append the node's RTT data into nodesRTT?
   for example:
   `nodesRTT[currNode].append(rttCur)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. The expression `len(nodes)` is evaluated at the line it is declared. It starts being `0`, and since its value is never updated by the code, it will remain zero.
2. Instead of a 2D list, of a `defaultdict(list)`. Then, you can directly do `nodesRTT[currNode].append(rttCur)]`. Since you are referring by node value, and not by position, a dict is a more appropriate data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Example of multi-dimensional array append:

```
nodeList = []
nodeSizeList = []

nodeOne = "nodeOne"
nodeList.append(nodeOne)
nodeSizeList.append([nodeList[0],len(nodeOne)])

print(nodeList)       # ['nodeOne']
print(nodeSizeList)   # [['nodeOne', 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have pasted, nodes list is expanded if string " from Node:" found in line and if that node not exist already. Where as nodesRTT updated only when string "RTT:" is present in line.

For second question, you can have a look at below code, you will get an idea about how to append in 2d list:

```
a = [[2]]
b = 3
d = []    
d.append(b) #Appending in 1d list
a.append(d) #Appending in 2d list  
print(a[0][0]) 
print(a[1][0])
```